# Why scanf() can't filter double quatation mark, although set format to [A-Za-z]

Tags: c, string, scanf, standard-library

I am trying to extract only letter words except the other characters in the sentence.

For this, I use two scanf() as bellow.

```
scanf("%s", word);
sscanf(word, "%[A-Za-z]", word);
```

Problem is that, double quatation mark on is not removed, although I set format to %[A-Za-z]
Curiously, however, if this mark on the last location on the word, it removed.

Is there anyone know reason?
Test case
- "Disneyland
- Left."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD    128

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char word[MAX_WORD];

    /* Read all of contents */
    while (EOF != scanf("%s", word)) {
        printf("origin word: %s\n", word);
        sscanf(word, "%[A-Za-z\"]s", word);
        printf("transformed: %s\n", word);

    }   
 }
```

Comment: uh... can the target be the same as the read string for `sscanf`? looks scary... any overly enthusiastic language lawyers here?

Comment: Are you expecting `sscanf()` to skip over the first quotation mark?  I think it would just return without reading anything (leaving the contents of `word` untouched).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, it's _probably_ safe but I base that on nothing more than how I'd implement `sscanf`, at least for this particular use case :-)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for some mistake on my contents. I've modified it. And, My purpose is that extract only a letter using sscanf() from standard input. I just want to know whether it is occurred by my wrong usage or limitation of sscanf.

Comment: The behaviour of `%[` is implementation-defined if the string contains `-` . So this code is relying on whatever libc implementation your system has, as opposed to Standard C.

Answer (score 1):

It's stripping off the end of the second line because of the *period,* not the quote, hence it's stripping both the period *and* the quote.

You have asked it to scan a string consisting of the letters `A-Za-z^"` so the presence of the period causes it to stop at that point.

I'm not sure if you totally understand how that works. It *won't* give you all characters in the string that match the ones you've specified, throwing away the rest. Instead it will accept characters up to the first valid one and then throw everything else away. You can see this if you type in some perfectly valid characters with an invalid one in the middle:

```
abcdefg.hijklmnop
origin word: abcdefg.hijklmnop
transformed: abcdefg
```

From that, it's evident that it stops at the *first* invalid character rather than just stripping out the invalid characters.

If you want a string with only matching characters, you can use something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD 128

static void strip(char *word, char *allow) {
    char *d = word;
    while (*word != '\0') {
        if (strchr (allow, *word) != NULL)
            *d++ = *word;
        word++;
    }
    *d = '\0';
}

int main (void) {
    char word[MAX_WORD];

    while (EOF != scanf ("%s", word)) {
        printf("origin word: %s\n", word);
        strip (word, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz^\"");
        printf("transformed: %s\n", word);
    }
}
```

and, with a sample set of runs:

```
"Disneyland
origin word: "Disneyland
transformed: "Disneyland

Left."
origin word: Left."
transformed: Left"

dvsdhjshhvsdf6553785365^%%$$@@#*&*&mjdvsdddhvjhdfvb
origin word: dvsdhjshhvsdf6553785365^%%$$@@#*&*&mjdvsdddhvjhdfvb
transformed: dvsdhjshhvsdf^mjdvsdddhvjhdfvb
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest and source. But I think, period is not a reason for skipping double quotation mark which is on end of sentence. For example, sscanf with [A-Za-z] format can change [Left"] to [Left].

Comment: @joejo, scanning `[Left"]` will fail totally because the `[` is not valid. Scanning `Left"` (assuming the `[]` were delimiters in your comment) will strip the `"` because it's the first invalid character (it also refuses to scan the rest of the string but that's not apparent since `"` is the last character). Scanning `Left.xyzzy` will stop at the `.`, throwing away the `xyzzy` as well. I suggest you read up on the `fscanf` doco, it doesn't behave the way you seem to think it does. It stops scanning at the _first_ invalid character, and I've updated the answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         sscanf(word, "%[A-Za-z\"]s", word);
> ```

**Programming languages — C** - **The `sscanf` function** - **Description**:

> … If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, your usage of `sscanf` is invalid. That said, the outcome of your test case is what is to be expected even from a correct usage; an explanation is embedded in paxdiablo's answer.